# Can boost::smart_ptr be used in polymorphism?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-smart-ptr

Can [boost::smart_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) such as scoped_ptr and shared_ptr be used in polymorphism?

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass()
    {
        a_ptr.reset(new SubClass);
    }
private:
    boost::scoped_ptr<SuperClass> a_ptr;
}
```

Comment: @Noah, I've tried and had memory leaks. I wasn't sure this was the reason, so I wanted to consult.

Comment: Time to start looking for circular references I suppose. :)

Comment: @Jonathan: Is your destructor virtual?

Comment: @Martin - Would not having a destructor in the superclass be ok? Also - it happens to be a struct, does that matter?

Comment: @Jonathan:  The `virtual` dtor needs to be int he base class.  `struct` versus `class` matters not one little bit.  See my updated post.

Comment: In fact, when using `shared_ptr`, you are almost always safe even if the base class destructor is not virtual.

Comment: @James: Correct (because `shared_ptr` calls the subclass's destructor, so the base class destructor can even be protected), but `scoped_ptr`'s constructor is not templatized.

Comment: Oh.  It must be almost beer-o-clock on Friday afternoon.  I totally read `scoped_ptr` as `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Philip - not entirely true.  The shared_ptr constructor takes a "deleter" as a parameter in addition to a pointer of type T (T being any type, not the type the shared_ptr was instantiated with).  This parameter defaults to calling delete on a pointer of type T (again, constructor's T, not ptr's).  So, so long as you construct your shared_ptr with the most derived type it works correctly even without a virtual destructor.  If you don't...then you've just stabbed yourself in the base of the skull.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <boost\shared_ptr.hpp>
using namespace boost;


class Foo
{
public:
    virtual string speak() const { return "Foo"; }
    virtual ~Foo() {};
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    string speak() const { return "Bar"; }
};

int main()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<Foo> my_foo(new Bar);
    cout << my_foo->speak();
}
```

Output is: `Bar`

Answer (score 6):

I believe the answer is yes; boost pointers are coded such that derived classes are accepted wherever a superclass would be.