# Can boost::smart_ptr be used in std containers?

Tags: c++, boost, polymorphism, containers

Can boost::smart_ptr such as scoped_ptr and shared_ptr be used in std containers such as std::map?

```
class SomeClass
{
    std::map<int,boost::scoped_ptr<SomeOtherClass> > a_map;
};
```

As [boost::smart_ptr can be used for polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763814/can-boostscoped-ptr-be-used-in-polymorphism), is it true in this case as well? Will the destruction of the container, trigger the correct destruction of the subclasses?

Comment: same thing as before : have you tried ?

Comment: @BatchyX - nope. It's quite a lot of refactoring in my case, so I rather ask. Besides, if the answer isn't on StackOverflow, it should be :)

Comment: Been there, done that. But I have learned from it, in most case you can write 20-30 line test programs that will verify/invalidate an idea in less than 5 minutes. `struct test { ~test() { std::cout << "~test" << std::endl; } }; int main() { vector<shared_ptr<type> > v; v.push_back( make_shared<test>() ); }` (or something in this line, its hard to write code in a comment). Then compile and verify whether destructors are called or not. Try again with `scoped_ptr` and see if the code even compiles. Throw in a couple other operations (`resize`, ...) and verify.

Comment: You guys are right. I should really develop this habit :) Even if I do, I guess I'll still ask the same questions on StackOverflow, because I like the interaction here. The answers are never boolean, I always learn the wider context. For instance, in this case I actually found that scoped_ptr cannot be used in containers before I submitted the question, but I submitted it nonetheless and Billy ONeal referred me to the pointer containers which I wasn't aware of and now I'll go read about them...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`scoped_ptr` cannot be used in standard containers because it cannot be copied (which is required by the containers' interfaces). `shared_ptr` may be used, however.

If you can't use C++11 and you're using boost already, consider the [pointer containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) which will perform somewhat better than a container of shared pointers.

If you're using C++11, consider a container of `unique_ptr`, which should perform similarly to boost's pointer containers.

Comment: @John Dibling: Win? Since when are we in a competition? :)