# How to use boost::smart_ptr in polymorphism?

Tags: casting, polymorphism, boost-smart-ptr

Boost smart pointers [can be used with polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763814/can-boostsmart-ptr-be-used-in-polymorphism), but how do you cast the subclass back to the pointer?

```
using namespace boost;
// ...
shared_ptr<SuperClass> a_ptr(new SubClass);
// ...
shared_ptr<SubClass> b_ptr = (shared_ptr<SubClass>)a_ptr; // Doesn't compile
```

The last line doesn't compile and gives `error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'boost::shared_ptr<T>' to 'boost::shared_ptr<T>'`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `static_pointer_cast`:

```
struct B { virtual ~B() { } };
struct D : B { };

shared_ptr<B> bp(new D);
shared_ptr<D> dp(static_pointer_cast<D>(b));
```

(There are also `dynamic_pointer_cast` and `const_pointer_cast` for performing dynamic and const casts respectively.)

Comment: I think that should be `dynamic_pointer_cast` in this case, right?

Comment: If it is unknown at compile time if the type is the one specified in the <> that is. Else boost::static_pointer_cast should be used.