# error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'const std::vector<_Ty> &`

Tags: c++, boost

Question1> Why the following code doesn't work?

Question2> What is the correct way to design it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "boost/shared_ptr.hpp"

using namespace std;

class BaseClass
{};

class SubClass : public BaseClass
{};

int main()
{
    std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<SubClass> > vecSubClassShared;

    boost::shared_ptr<SubClass> sub1(new SubClass);

    vecSubClassShared.push_back(sub1);

    // Error    1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'const std::vector<_Ty> &`
    const std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass> >& vecBaseShared = vecSubClassShared;
}
```

Comment: My gut tells me that (if it's possible) it's an ugly solution, given the fact that just casting a single `boost::shared_ptr<SubClass>` to a `boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass>` requires [`static_pointer_cast`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764398/how-to-use-boostsmart-ptr-in-polymorphism)

Comment: I have used a single `boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass>` which is initialized with `boost::shared_ptr<SubClass>` and it works as expected. Just curious, why the collection of such things doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

In the view of the C++ compiler, `shared_ptr<BaseClass>` and `shared_ptr<DerivedClass>` are different, unrelated types. While the compiler knows, that normal Pointers can be converted from `Derived*` to `Base*`, it does not know that conceptually the same should apply for `shared_ptr`s, because it does not know "smart pointers" being pointer-like.

The same applies for vector or for templates in general: two instantiations of a template are two different class, with no relation betwen them (if not designed explicitly). So the compiler sees a `vector<Something>` bound to a reference to a `vector<SomethingElse>` which are not related types, so the reference binding fails.

But even if the types were somehow related, the binding would fail:

```
long l = 5;
int& ir = l; //ERROR
```

Answer (score 1):

`shared_ptr<BaseClass>` and `shared_ptr<SubClass>` are distinct, unrelated types, so there's no way for a vector of one to alias a vector of the other, because there's no guarantee that their object layout is the same.

This means that to e.g. pass `const std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass> >&` to a function you'll have to construct a temporary vector of the desired type.  You can however do this without incrementing the reference counts on the shared pointers, using shared pointer aliasing:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct B {};
struct D: public B {};

template<typename T, typename U>
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> shared_vector_static_cast(
   const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<U>> &v)
{
   std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> w;
   for (const std::shared_ptr<U> &p: v)
      w.push_back(std::shared_ptr<T>(std::shared_ptr<void>(), p.get()));
   return w;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<D>> v{std::make_shared<D>()};
    const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>> &w = shared_vector_static_cast<B>(v);
}
```

Comment: There is a bug in the code. The size of w is the end is 2*v.size() rather than v.size().